# Matlab generate all possible team combinations

Tags: matlab, combinations, discrete-mathematics

There's lots of questions that are similar to mine but I haven't found quite what I'm looking for yet.
I'm working on a project to optimize teaming in a class, and am not sure how to generate all possible team combinations.

Say I have a vector that's a list of numbered people, like

```
<1,2,3,4,5....,n>
```

I want to generate all possible combinations of teams with `k` people per team, where `k` is smaller than `n`. 
The output should be matrices where the rows are the teams. Each matrix will have `k` columns, and `n/k` rows (corresponding to the number of teams).

For example, say my vector is`<1,2,3,4>`. I want all combinations of teams of 2. My possible output matrices would be `[1,2;3,4]`,`[1,3;2,4]`, and `[1,4;2,3]`. I'd like to know how to scale this up to any `n` and `k` value.

Comment: Do you have the Neural Networks Toolbox?

Comment: Is n divisible by k?

Comment: Yes n needs to be divisible by k. My bad.

Comment: And I don't believe I have the Toolbox, I have found some references to it in other possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done only some incomplete testing, but this seems to work.

**Code**:

```
%// Data:
n = 6; %// number of people
k = 2; %// team size. Assumed to divide p

%// Let's go:
M = unique(perms(ceil((1:n)/k)), 'rows').'; %'// the transpose is for convenience
result = NaN(n/k, k, size(M,2)); %// preallocate
for t = 1:n/k
    [ii, ~] = find(M==t);
    result(t,:,:) = reshape(ii, k, []);
end
result = result(:,:,all(diff(result(:,1,:))>0, 1));
```

The result matrices are given by `result(:,:,1)`, `result(:,:,2)` etc.

**Explanation**:

The key steps are:

- Line `M = unique(perms(ceil((1:n)/k)), 'rows').'`: this assigns `k` different team numbers, one to each group of `n/k` people, and creates all different permutations of those numbers. So this includes all possible team groupings.
- `for` loop: this translates the above representation into the matrix format you want: each team is described by a row containing `n/k` labels from the set {1,2,...,*n*}, telling which people belong to that team. Within each row, those labels are always increasing.
- Line `result = result(:,:,all(diff(result(:,1,:))>0, 1))`: this removes matrices that are row-permutations of others. It does so by keeping only matrices whose first column is increasing.

**Examples**:

For `n=4; k=2`,

```
>> result
result(:,:,1) =
     1     2
     3     4
result(:,:,2) =
     1     3
     2     4
result(:,:,3) =
     1     4
     2     3
```

For `n=6; k=2`,

```
>> result
result(:,:,1) =
     1     2
     3     4
     5     6
result(:,:,2) =
     1     2
     3     5
     4     6
result(:,:,3) =
     1     2
     3     6
     4     5
result(:,:,4) =
     1     3
     2     4
     5     6
...
```

Answer (score 1):

It is quite overkilling, but it seems to work:

```
n = 4;
k = 2;

allCombinations = perms(1:n);

numComb = size(allCombinations,1);
selCombinations = zeros(size(allCombinations));
cellCombinations = cell(numComb,1);
for ii = 1:numComb
    candidate = sortrows(sort(reshape(allCombinations(ii,:),[],k),2));
    selCombinations(ii,:) = candidate(:);
    cellCombinations{ii} = candidate;
end

[~,idx] = unique(selCombinations, 'rows');
cellCombinations{idx}
```

I create all the possible combinations of `n` elements, and then I select the unique combinations that follow your criteria.

Comment: Nice. But i think for larger cases like n=6 and k=2 one will also need to remove the cases where the teams are in different order.

Comment: Agreed, the order of the teams in the matrix doesn't matter.